# If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a closed differentiable function, then $\exists t\in(a,b)$ such that $\langle f(t),f'(t)\rangle=0$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed differentiable function. Show that there exists $t\in(a,b)$ such that $\langle f(t),f'(t)\rangle=0$.

Could someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: By "closed differentiable function" do you mean a function parametrising a closed curve?

Comment: Here is what I mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps

Comment: Are you sure? The map $f(t) = (1-a+t,0,0)$ is closed in that sense but has $f'(t)=(1,0,0)$ and thus $\langle f(t),f'(t) \rangle = 1-a+t > 0$ for all $t \ge a$.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong (but this was the definition that author used in first chapter). And in the first section of the second chapter (where is the exercise), there is no definition of "closed function". But you are right and I will verify the next sections because I think that correct definition is there... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the product rule we have $$\langle f(t),f'(t)\rangle = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \Vert f \Vert^2.$$
Consider the function $\Vert f \Vert^2 : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and apply the Mean Value Theorem.