# $\lambda:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ differentiable closed path, then exists $t\in(a,b)$ such that $\langle\lambda(t),\lambda'(t)\rangle = 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $\lambda:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable closed path.
> Show that there exists $t\in(a,b)$ such that
> $\langle\lambda(t),\lambda'(t)\rangle = 0$

I understand this intuitively: given a path restriected to $[a,b]$, we should find a point such that the function itself is perpendicular to its derivative. I can imagine it for some cases, but what about the case below:
[image]

As you can see, the vector $f(t)$ is not perpendicular to $f'(t_0)$ for any $t_0$.

Also, about this proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/460207/166180, could somebody help me
understanding this formula:

$$\langle f(t),f'(t)\rangle = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \Vert f \Vert^2$$

and how the mean value theorem would help?

Comment: That's not a closed path.

Comment: By closed path, you need $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's restricted to closed paths, so, we have that $f(a)=f(b)$ and hence $\Vert f(b)\Vert^2=\Vert f(a)\Vert^2$. By the mean value theorem, for some $t_c$, $a\lt t_c\lt b$

$$\dfrac{\Vert f(b)\Vert^2-\Vert f(a)\Vert^2}{b-a}=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\Vert f(t_c)\Vert^2=0=\langle f(t),f'(t)\rangle$$

It's very intuitive the result in fact. As much as $f(c)=kf'(c)$ for some $c$ (and some restriction, in fact).

**Addendum**

$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\Vert f \Vert^2=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\langle f,f\rangle=\langle f',f\rangle+\langle f,f'\rangle=2\langle f',f\rangle$